# how can I check which p was clicked and what innerhtml he contains with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, innerhtml

hellow I have a problem,
I want my page to check which p was clicked and what is his innerhtml and acoording to that to change img size.
you can see it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/YgL5Z/

or

my html:

```
<div class="one_of_4_colum"><p class="mysizeNum" onclick="mySize()">4</p></div>
  <div class="one_of_4_colum"><p class="mysizeNum" onclick="mySize()">3</p></div>
  <div class="one_of_4_colum"><p class="mysizeNum" onclick="mySize()">2</p></div>
  <div class="one_of_4_colum"><p class="mysizeNum" onclick="mySize()">1</p></div>
<img class="myPreviewElmo">
```

my js

```
 function mySize()
        {
            if ((this.innerHTML) == "4") {
                $('.myPreviewElmo').css('height', '200px');
            }
            if (this.innerHTML == "3") {
                $('.myPreviewElmo').css('height', '150px');
            }
            if (this.innerHTML == "2") {
                $('.myPreviewElmo').css('height', '100px');
            }
            if (this.innerHTML == "1") {
                $('.myPreviewElmo').css('height', '50px');
            }
        }
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$(".mysizeNum").click(function() {
    var innerText = parseInt($(this).text());
    var height = innerText * 50;
    $('.myPreviewElmo').css('height', height + "px");
})
```

Comment: Was just about to post something very similar.  One note - you don't need the "px" when setting the css property.  It assumes pixels if you don't specify a unit :)

Comment: @Archer that's just splitting hairs... It doesn't matter.

Comment: @JoshSmickus It wasn't a criticism, I was just making a point that other people may want to know.  I already upvoted the answer as correct, so I obviously don't think there's anything *wrong* with it.

Comment: @Archer no worries, it's just a different edge of the same sword ;)

Answer (score 0):

Firslty, don't use `on*` event attributes. They are outdated and not good for separation of concerns. Attach events in jQuery instead. Also, you can use `data-*` attributes to simplify your code:

```
<div class="one_of_4_colum">
    <p class="mysizeNum" data-height="200px">4</p>
</div>
<div class="one_of_4_colum">
    <p class="mysizeNum" data-height="150px">3</p>
</div>
<div class="one_of_4_colum">
    <p class="mysizeNum" data-height="100px">2</p>
</div>
<div class="one_of_4_colum">
    <p class="mysizeNum" data-height="50px">1</p>
</div>
<div class="myPreviewElmo">
```

```js
$('.mysizeNum').click(function () {
     $('.myPreviewElmo').css('height', $(this).data('height'));
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/YgL5Z/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="one_of_4_colum">
    <p class="mysizeNum" data-size="4">4</p>
</div>
<div class="one_of_4_colum">
    <p class="mysizeNum" data-size="3">3</p>
</div>
<div class="one_of_4_colum">
    <p class="mysizeNum" data-size="2">2</p>
</div>
<div class="one_of_4_colum">
    <p class="mysizeNum" data-size="1">1</p>
</div>
<div class="myPreviewElmo">
```

then

```
jQuery(function () {
    var heights = {
        'size-1': '50px',
        'size-2': '100px',
        'size-3': '150px',
        'size-4': '200px'
    }
    $('.mysizeNum').click(function () {
        $('.myPreviewElmo').css('height', heights['size-' + $(this).data('size')]);
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v5LBy/)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML should be like this -

```
<div class="one_of_4_colum"><p class="mysizeNum">4</p></div>
  <div class="one_of_4_colum"><p class="mysizeNum">3</p></div>
  <div class="one_of_4_colum"><p class="mysizeNum">2</p></div>
  <div class="one_of_4_colum"><p class="mysizeNum">1</p></div>
<div class="myPreviewElmo"></div>
```

And your javascript -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mysizeNum').click(function() {
        $('.myPreviewElmo').height(parseInt($(this).text())*50);
    });
});
```

In addition, make sure in the fiddle you select jQuery library as enabled.

Answer (score 0):

There were so many things wrong with your code, so I just rewrote most of it with this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/YgL5Z/7/  There's probably still room for improvement, but this gets the job done quite neatly.

```
$(function () {
    $(".mysizeNum").click(function() {
        var newheight=(parseInt($(this).text())*50);
        $('.myPreviewElmo').height(newheight);
    });
});
```